# Remove favicon from ASP.Net MVC Application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, favicon

I have an ASP.Net MVC Application. I want to remove the `favicon` from my browser tab, but I am not able to do so.

I have deleted the `favicon.ico` from my application and also put the below piece of code in `Route.config` to ignore `favicon.ico`

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Also, there is no `<link rel="icon">` in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure this is not just a browser caching issue?

Comment: Your browser is caching the favicon. Try clearing the cache

Comment: @trashr0x: This is not a caching issue as I have cleared the cache.  I just cannot find where this favicon is referenced. Any other thing that I may be missing out ?

Comment: @Nkosi : This is not a caching issue as I have cleared the cache. I just cannot find where this favicon is referenced. Any other thing that I may be missing out ?

Comment: Have you tried using a totally different browser, just to be doubly sure its not a caching issue? You dont need a favicon reference for it to show up, browsers will request this by default whether you specify it or not. Removing it from disk should just fix the problem.

Comment: @LDJ - Yes checked in another browser as well, but it is still showing up. It is no where in my disk also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the `favicon.ico` file (from disk) and also not referencing it anywhere in your HTML (using `<link rel="icon" ...` in `<head>` tag) should solve the problem.

However, due to caching, your browser might still show the icon. Try a hard refresh (Ctrl + Shift + R in most browsers).

Comment: I have cleared the cache, but still it is showing up. I just cannot find where this favicon is referenced. Any other thing that I may be missing out ?

Comment: @Alorika are you sure the file is physically gone from your disk, not just from your MVC project?

Comment: Yes I have checked thrice, there is no `favicon.ico` in my disk and I have checked in another browser as well, but still it is showing up. Is it possible, it is getting referenced from any external JS or CDN or somewhere else?

Comment: You should see the request for the file in the network tab of your browser. What does that return? The request is by default to your application root \ favicon.ico unless your meta data specifies otherwise

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester - You were right. I put `<link href="#" rel="icon">` in the `<head>` tag but did not give reference to any other image. Now, the `favicon.ico` has disappeared. Though, it shows a blank space in the browser tab just before the title, but that can be ignored in my case. But I would still like to know, if we can remove that blank space somehow?

Comment: @Alorika you've misunderstood my answer - you need to *delete* the `<link>` from your HTML. What if you delete it now - does it still find the old icon somewhere?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: After deleting the `<link>`, it does not find the old icon back. I am now really confused of this behavior.

Comment: @Alorika it is as others have mentioned, a browser cache issue. I've experienced weird behavior with favicons in Firefox in the past as well, it seems that the default `/favicon.ico` is cached more rigorously than other requests.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: Thanks :)